# how to leave a mark when scrolling down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I make a rainbow which leaves a trail when you scroll down, as shown in the picture?

[image]

Comment: stretch an image?? Unclear what is supposed to happen and it feels like code it for it...

Comment: @epascarello rainbow must follow scrolling down

Comment: does it grow? is it static?

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, the trail will move down the page as you scroll down, assuming the starting point gets higher in the browser window as you scroll down? What will happen when scrolling up?

One way to do this would be to use a 1px high background image to create your rainbow, set CSS `background-repeat: repeat-y` and use Javascript to increase/decrease the height of the element as the user scrolls, based on how far they scroll past the trail's starting position.